# Numeric Prefix in Hostname

Tags: system-installation, hostname

In the Ubuntu Server Installer, we are precluded from placing a number as the first character in a hostname. However, once installed, we can issue a hostname command to rename the server to have a numeric prefix. Is there a reason for this limitation?

As an example, in the installer, I could create a hostname of

```
WebServer1
```

but NOT

```
0WebServer1
```

I can, however, create a server with a name of

```
WebServer1
```

then, in the CLI, rename it to

```
0WebServer1
```

Please advise why this limitation is in place and if there are any caveats to working around it.

Answer (score 4):

Historic reasons, probably.

[RFC 952](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc952), published in 1985, with the title of *DOD INTERNET HOST TABLE SPECIFICATION* mandates that hostnames contains letters (a-z) and digits (0-9), and cannot start with a digit:

> 1. A "name" (Net, Host, Gateway, or Domain name) is a text string up
>    to 24 characters drawn from the alphabet (A-Z), digits (0-9), minus
>    sign (-), and period (.).  Note that periods are only allowed when
>    they serve to delimit components of "domain style names". (See
>    RFC-921, "Domain Name System Implementation Schedule", for
>    background).  No blank or space characters are permitted as part of a
>    name. No distinction is made between upper and lower case.  **The first
>    character must be an alpha character.  The last character must not be
>    a minus sign or period.**  A host which serves as a GATEWAY should have
>    "-GATEWAY" or "-GW" as part of its name.  Hosts which do not serve as
>    Internet gateways should not use "-GATEWAY" and "-GW" as part of
>    their names. A host which is a TAC should have "-TAC" as the last
>    part of its host name, if it is a DoD host.  Single character names
>    or nicknames are not allowed.

(My emphasis).

This was changed in [RFC 1123](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123#page-13), four years later:

> The syntax of a legal Internet host name was specified in RFC-952 [DNS:4].  One aspect of host name syntax is hereby changed: the restriction on the first character is relaxed to allow either a letter or a digit.  Host software MUST support this more liberal syntax.

So whilst the latter is allowable today, it has not always been so, and I'm guessing it's an convention that is still held by quite a few today, which is why programmers has (wrongly) enforced this.

IMO it could be [submitted as a bug towards the installer](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity).

It will work on modern systems, and you should see no issues on modern platforms that conforms to modern DNS standards.